# Scroll function from DevEd tutorial is not working

Tags: javascript, html, smooth-scrolling

I've watched this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUSvlrDTLi4 and I was doing the same thing as here, I only replaced var to let with ES6 standard.

```js
function scroll(target, duration = 1000) {
  target = document.querySelector(target) + window.scrollY;
  let targetPos = terget.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let startPos = window.pageYOffset;
  let distance = targetPos - startPos;
  let startTime = null;

  function animation(currentTime) {
    if (startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
    let timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
    let run = ease(timeElapsed, startPos, distance, duration);
    window.scrollTo(0, run);
    if (timeElapsed < duration) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
  }

  function ease(t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d / 2;
    if (t < 1) return c / 2 * t * t + b;
    t--;
    return -c / 2 * (t * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="a">
    <h1 onclick="scroll('.b', 1000)">Scroll</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h1 onclick="scroll('.a', 1000)">Scroll</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the function name to not conflict with `window.scroll`.
2. `target` should be the element itself or `document.querySelector(target)`.
3. `target` was spelled wrong on the second line of the function.

```js
function myScroll(target, duration = 1000) {
  target = document.querySelector(target);
  let targetPos = target.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  let startPos = window.pageYOffset;
  let distance = targetPos - startPos;
  let startTime = null;

  function animation(currentTime) {
    if (startTime === null) startTime = currentTime;
    let timeElapsed = currentTime - startTime;
    let run = ease(timeElapsed, startPos, distance, duration);
    window.scrollTo(0, run);
    if (timeElapsed < duration) requestAnimationFrame(animation);
  }

  function ease(t, b, c, d) {
    t /= d / 2;
    if (t < 1) return c / 2 * t * t + b;
    t--;
    return -c / 2 * (t * (t - 2) - 1) + b;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .a {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: green;
    }
    
    .b {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="a">
    <h1 onclick="myScroll('.b', 1000)">Scroll</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <h1 onclick="myScroll('.a', 1000)">Scroll</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Python_Programmer Did you run the code snippet? It works for me.

Comment: wow its working on the snippet, but not for html in browser

Comment: @Python_Programmer Are you using the exact same code?

Comment: @Python_Programmer Could you provide a [mcve] of the problem?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @Python_Programmer Can you create a snippet that shows the code not working? If not, I can't help.

Comment: @Python_Programmer Did you get it to work?